# How to center a Delphi form on a 4k screen? (Windows scaling enabled) - poScreenCenter not working

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a Delphi form functioning as a sort of splash screen (i.e. borderless) that I want to appear exactly in the center of the (main) screen (currently using TForm1.Position := poScreenCenter to achieve this).

This is not working on 4k monitors with scaling (or any screen really that uses a percentage higher than 100% in Windows (Settings > Display > Scale and Layout)). In such cases, the form will pop up *more in the upper left-hand corner* rather than the exact middle of the screen. This seems like a HiDPI-related bug in Delphi, as the program looks otherwise fine and works well.

My guess is that I would have to set TForm1.Position to poDesigned and manually set TForm1.Top and Left in the OnShow event. The question is: To what? What would be a universal solution to ensure that the form always appears in the exact screen center, regardless of monitor size / resolution / scaling etc. I have stumbled across a function called "muldiv" that may be of help but I am unsure how to use it.

I have:

- Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899
- Windows 10 Version 20H2
- DPI awareness (Project > Options > Application > Manifest) set to "System Aware"
- TForm1.Scaled set to "True"
- TForm1.PixelsPerInch set to "96"
- TForm1.FormStyle set to "fsStayOnTop"
- TForm1.BorderStyle set to "bsNone"
- TForm1.Position set to "poScreenCenter"
- TFrom1.DefaultMonitor set to "dmActiveForm"
- TForm1.Width and Height both set to "480"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried something like Form1.Left := (Screen.Width - Form1.Width) div 2; and same for top ?

Comment: @fpiette: actually, it shouldn't be Screen.Width but Form1.Monitor.Width etc. But that works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To center the form, use this code:

```
Form1.Left := (Form1.Monitor.Width  - Form1.Width)  div 2;
Form1.Top  := (Form1.Monitor.Height - Form1.Height) div 2;
```

Of course you may check that the form is not bigger than the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
Form1.Left := (Screen.WorkAreaRect.Width  - Form1.Width)  div 2;
Form1.Top  := (Screen.WorkAreaRect.Height - Form1.Height) div 2;
```